# Eclipse wont create JLabels

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, jlabel, absolute

I'm having this issue with Eclipse. I have an app window that has 3 `JTextFields`. I want everytime to check if the field has an acceptable value and if not, create under it a JLabel in red that will indicate the error.

Because I used **AbsoluteLayout**, I needed to know the coordinates of the `JLabel` for the setBounds() method.

So what I did was create the `Jlabels` from the Design Tab (to get the coordinates), then I click on them and then I went to their code. With the design manager, the red `JLabel` would be visible right from the start and that is not what should happen.

So I copied the code which created the `JLabel` via the Design Tab, and placed it inside a `MouseEvent` so every time the user will hit the button to make something in my program, I will check the values and if something is wrong, I create the `JLabel` with the same code inside the `" if clause"` which checks for the input values. The thing is that my `JLabel` wont create it self and that's the issue with all of my `"if" clauses` inside my program.

For example, this JLabel never gets created,no matter what value I give:

```
String sql_year = year.getText();
// year is my JTextField()
if((sql_year.length()>5)||(sql_year.length()<4))
{
    JLabel digit = new JLabel("Error. Year is a 4-5 digit number!!");
    digit.setForeground(Color.RED);
    digit.setBounds(221, 126, 222, 38);
    frame.getContentPane().add(digit);
    digit.setVisible(true);
    year.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Eclipse...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: you mean add the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after you add the `JLabel` :

```
frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```